# Find process ID of a background process

Tags: linux

I am execute a infinite while loop from command line that would execute a rest call with the use of CURL . I'm redirecting the rest o/p to a file . I have appended an "&" at the end of the command so that it goes into background.
Unfortunately, the terminal was exited .
But I see the process is still writing the o/p to the file continuously . 
However I don't see any background jobs running with the command job.
Even I used **ps/lsof/fuser** to find the process ID so that I can manually kill it.
But none of the commands returned me the process ID. 
I even tried changing the file to read only mode, but still I see the file continuously growing.

At last I found chattr command that would restrict the file from being written.

But in this case where would I find the process ID that is responsible .

```
touch /var/log/test_mon_vm.log;while true; echo "start....." >>/var/log/test_mon_vm.log;echo $(date) >> /var/log/test_mon_vm.log; do /usr/bin/curl -I --user rhqadmin:rhqadmin http://localhost:7080/rest/plugins?name=Samba 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 >> /var/log/test_mon_vm.log; echo "end....." >> /var/log/test_mon_vm.log;echo >>/var/log/test_mon_vm.log;echo >>/var/log/test_mon_vm.log;sleep 1;done &
```

Comment: can you mention the `while` loop code?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ID with

```
ps -fea|grep [your USER]
```

then search the script list, there's gonna be, if you use an script replace your user with the script name

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fg`

[Background Processes in linux](http://www.astro.ku.dk/comp-phys/tutorials/background.shtml)

once the background process is in the foreground you can kill it using `ctrl+c`

I hope this helps! Have a nice day!

Comment: there were no background process that I see when I use the command **job**

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ps aux | grep "command-you-ran"
```

e.g.

```
ps aux | grep "curl"
```

Comment: I don't see the process in the process table .